# Single word for get (find) or create

Tags: word-request

Is there a word denoting an action after some object appears but it's unknown whether it was found or created?

Single variant I have is `arrange` but I doubt that it fits perfectly. What are some other variants?

Comment: Feels like I'm asking question that was asked many times before bu I cannot find anything useful.

Comment: This question needs to be re-written, I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: *arrange* doesn't mean anything like what you describe.  Maybe [obtain](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obtain) is the word you want?

Comment: [Acquire](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acquire) could work. To come into possession of something is to [possess](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/possess) it.

Comment: Why not simply ask, "Where did you get this?" this may mean aquire, create, steal, find, obtain, get, earn.

Comment: @SovereignSun Doesn't this imply that it existed before?

Comment: Perhaps a real example can help. At the moment, I don't understand why something can "appear" but was not "created" (or "came into existence").

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to use the word "[obtain](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obtain)" in your context.

"Obtain" means "get" or "achieve".  "Achieve" and "create" have some overlap.  Something can be "obtained" either legally or illegally.  Thus, "obtain" is sometimes used when the speaker wants to be vague about whether something was bought, borrowed, stolen, or "cobbled together".

Comment: Great explanation! How often is `achieve` used with tangible objects?

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov -- "Achieve" is sometimes used with tangible objects that represent intangible ideas.  For example, Boy Scout merit badges, earning a diploma, or coming up with a way to make a tangible object.

Answer (score 2):

**Come from**

In American English at least, it is common to ask where something *comes from.*

Maybe the answer has to do with causality:

> Q: Where did that bruise on your shin come from?
>
> A: I kicked a chair.

Maybe the answer has to do with some action taken by the person being queried:

> Q: Nice Hat!  Where'd that come from?
>
> A: I picked it up at a garage sale for fifty cents!

Maybe the answer has to do with unknown provenance:

> Q: That's a weird looking symbol on the wall there.  I wonder where it came from.
>
> A: Creepy! I am sure it wasn't there when I went to sleep last night.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for alternatives

> request (transitive), provide(intransitive/transitive)

might be a good options. Also for certain special cases:

> mount, ask, load, install, demand, etc.

comes to mind. All these options include looking for something and providing it, they do not specify whether that thing is created, searched, extracted, etc.